# Custom confirmBox usig

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, confirm

I'm not good with this JavaScript custom confirm box.

What I want: Custom Confirm Box {popup showing images & styled text}

Why I'm asking: I have conditions, on that custom confirm Box will shown,
On this custom confirm Box value, I have further condition.
That's why I stuck here!

My code:

```
var infoBox = false;

if (msgType=='1'){
  alert(msg);
  infoBox=confirm("Test1");
} else if(msgType=='2'){
  customConfirmBox(function(){
    alert(infoBox);
  });
} else {
   infoBox=confirm("Continue?");
}

if (infoBox){
  //code
  alert('done');
}

function customConfirmBox(callback){
  $('.confirmMsg').show();
  $('#alertAccepted').click(function() {
    input_box=true;
    callback();
  });
}
```

What happening with this code:
when msgType is 2, it shows popup proper, but then nothing happens,
Its not waiting for user input like confirm (') ;

How can I solve it;

Comment: whoa, this is pretty hard to read ... sorry man, I am lost in your code

Comment: @DavidVotrubec Sorry for that, but i'm totally stuck here, pasting again n again doesn't make any sense, finally  any how I finessed like this.
Again sorry for that